# Will isolating a clothes dryer make it safer if fire occurs?

Tags: fire-hazard, fireproof

i have installed my electric dryer in the basement about 2 feet from cinderblock wall. It is on tile and nothing else is close by except the washer a foot away and sewer pipe about 8 inches behind.
If there was a lint fire could it spread anywhere?

I guess what I am asking is what happens after lint and clothes inside burn. Will other things burn?

Comment: Does it use a NEMA 10 (3-prong) or NEMA 14 (4-prong) receptacle?

Comment: Where is the vent running, and how long is it? A short, direct, NO FLEX HOSE ANYWHERE easy to clean vent is the best way to never have to find out what happens when it catches on fire, because it's easy to keep clean so it doesn't. I've never had a dryer fire, my general understanding is that the vent full of lint which has air being blown through it turns into a bit of  torch for a while; but I lack personal experience. I do have personal experience cleaning out flex hose, and I will never use it again - smooth rigid duct all the way.

Comment: 4 prong. Why do you ask?

Comment: Solid metal vent pipe about 8 feet up from basement floor to out the wall  i did have a fire in old dryer before this one, which is why i am asking

Comment: @anncy Priorities.  Given that you take safety seriously,  a 3-prong NEMA 10 should not be overlooked, especially since retrofitting ground is now easy.

Comment: I do not understand why you would recommend switching from the new 4 prong to the old 3 prong standard. Unless i am reading wrong, the 4 prong is supposed to be safer

Comment: @harper or were you recommending 4 prong? Which is safer?

Comment: @Anncy sorry, I was recommending *to go **to*** 4-prong as the most important safety upgrade you can do on a dryer.

Comment: @harper  thank goodness. I do have the 4 prong. I  think i finally understand what it does.  now i am hoping my oven and all glass cooktop have 4 wires but at least the cooktop has no metal to touch anyway. They are from 2012-2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the fire spread? Yes I have seen dust, lint and cobwebs catch fire and quickly run up a concrete / cinder block wall to areas that could support combustion. keeping the pipe cleaned out and the area free of combustibles (dust, lint and others) will increase your safety.

Comment: I will make sure to eliminate all dust etc there. I was also wondering about the pvc pipe behind it and whether i should spray it and the floor joists above with some sort of flame retardant

Comment: Cover the floor joists above with Type X drywall if you want to protect them. Perhaps even two layers of it.

Comment: I would love to but I cannot do that myself and anyone who can would have to move pipes and elec wires